# AFNetworking returning NSCFData; issue with registerHTTPOperationClass

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am new to AFNetworking and am making a call to a simple login api that returns json like:

```
{"status":"success","data":{"auth_token":"12jt34"}}
```

I'm doing it via the following but it is returning __NSCFData rather than something that I can manipuate.

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/arc/v1/api/"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        uname,@"email", pwd, @"password",
                        nil];
[httpClient postPath:@"login-mobile" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([responseObject class]);
    NSLog(@"val: %@",className);
}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error retrieving data: %@", error);
}];
```

and it outputs:

```
2013-03-21 14:52:51.290 FbTabbed[21505:11303] val: __NSCFData
```

but I'd like it for it to be a dictionary that I can manipulate which is how I think it is supposed to work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest using your `AFHTTPClient` to create an `NSURLRequest` by calling `requestWithMethod:path:parameters:`, then using `AFJSONRequestOperation` to make that request and get JSON back.

Comment: thx Isaac - do they get to the same point; I think setting the registerHTTPOperationClass to AFJSONRequestOperation does that for you. If you know better, would be interested

Comment: It looks like you're making a POST request and sounds like you expect JSON back.  You can definitely do that and use the same `httpClient` object and all its settings while doing it by creating the request with something like `NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"login-mobile" parameters:params]; [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^{} failure:^{}];`  (fill in those blocks as appropriate).

Comment: yeah, so what you're describing is correct sending post'd data and getting back json. Honestly, our main object for handling this is separate, this was just to check an api end point (so no real issue of manaing httpClient_. I think manually setting the header value below is the way to go. It works fine but I'm sure it could be done dirrenently.

Comment: If you don't need to set the header, you can probably use `AFJSONRequestOperation` directly; if you are setting the header on a per-use basis you can generate the `NSURLRequest` and set the header on that, then feed it into `AFJSONRequestOperation`, same as I described before with the `httpClient`, just without the `httpClient` part.

Comment: fair enough, I think either way would work.  you can see that managing via httpClient also works in the comments here https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/97 . The example provided was just a snippet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];
```

should be:

```
[httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
```

Comment: No, this is not the problem. The problem is what I just described.

Comment: despite downvotes, this works. AFNetworking will deserialize for you.

Comment: I had the same issue and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `responseObject` is a `NSData`. You can then parse it into a dictionary or array using `NSJSONSerialization` method `JSONObjectWithData`:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/arc/v1/api/"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        uname,@"email", pwd, @"password",
                        nil];
[httpClient postPath:@"login-mobile" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSAssert([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSData class]], @"responseObject is supposed to be a NSData"); // it should be a NSData class

    NSError *error;
    self.results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
    if (error != nil)
    {
        // handle the error

        // an example of the sort of error that could result in a parse error 
        // is if common issue is that certain server errors can result in an
        // HTML error page (e.g. you have the URL wrong, your server will 
        // deliver a HTML 404 page not found page). If you want to look at the 
        // contents of the `responseObject`, you would:
        //
        // NSLog(@"responseObject=%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }
}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error retrieving data: %@", error);
}];
```

Obviously, your `results` object would be a `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`, depending upon the type of response you get from your API.

Comment: thx, I appreciate the answer. AFNetworking will do all of that now if you change the call that I had set as the answer.

Comment: @timpone I'm afraid I'm not following you. Did you solve your issue? I would have thought that my answer above, or better, Isaac's suggestion to use `AFJSONRequestOperation`, would have solved it. I'm unclear as to whether you still have an open question or not.

Comment: thx for follow-up, I answered which worked well for posting and getting back json. It works well and basically gives you back either NSArray or NSDictionary. I think H2CO3 unset it as the answer I accepted. Go figure - I'm too busy to deal with him (and have rolled a whole auth system since I asked this question)

Comment: @timpone lol. That's what I was confused about. I doubt that anyone "unset" the answer, but rather it just didn't "take". If you really wanted to accept his answer, I'd encourage you to just do so (otherwise this question hangs out there as unanswered). Your call. Regardless, I'm glad you've solved your problem and have moved on. I love it!

Comment: thx @Rob pretty sure the answer was unset as I had accepted it and he edited and now it's not set as the answer; anyways,  I upvoted your answer. It was just really a very simple syntax question not some discussion about magic and intropsection methods. More fore meta, but I always feel like there is some middle ground between SO and open-source library docs which are almost always outdated, vague, when you usually want the library to solve a fairly specific problem (and it was usually created to solve that problem). thx again for your time

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

`NSStringFromClass()` returns the name of the class you pass in as an `NSString` object.

If you want to make a dictionary out of the returned JSON string, then you have to parse it, for example using the `NSJSONSerialization` class.

Comment: ***Do explain the (wrong) downvote.***

Comment: People don't like the truth? or "Don't listen to what I'm saying, understand what I mean?"

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Possible, and quite sad if true.

Comment: I'm aware of all of the issues you mentioned. That's not what the question. It was a simple syntax question. Thx for answer though.

Comment: @H2CO3 I didn't down-vote, but I'd guess it's because of the tone of your answer, which is unnecessarily sarcastic. I don't know why you go out of your way to suggest that timpone must think that `NSStringFromClass` is magic or that he must not have read any documentation. It's an innocent misunderstanding. Don't get me wrong: I like the fact that you're active and helping people, but, IMHO, you often are unnecessarily snarky. (Notably, I think your comments about the innocent misuse of xcode tag are rude. We want to help, not belittle.) Be sarcastic if you want, but live with the down votes.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for your comment. My point: 1. downvotes are for indicating technical inaccuracies, not taste against style. This answer doesn't have technical inaccuracies. 2. OP really didn't read the documentation of `NSStringFromClass` - if he had, he wouldn't even have tried to use it for this purpose.

Comment: @H2CO3 1. We'll just have to agree to disagree on this point. :) This is better discussed on Meta (and has been, exhaustively; the consensus is that this is valid reason to down-vote). Like I said, I didn't down-vote, but I can understand why someone would. 2. I found timpone's attempt to `NSLog` a parameter's class name (esp an `id` type) a perfectly logical (albeit, incomplete) diagnostic technique, not some misguided belief in magic or failure to read the documentation. I only would have suggested that timpone took the next step and also converted it to a `NSString` and examined that.

Comment: thx Rob, I did output as NSString and isKindOfClass. Honestly, just trying to figure out some code a dev did that we let go. The answer I provided was what I was looking for and works fine the `what am I doing wrong?` wasn't about NSStringFromClass and I think that should be obvious from question. Apparently, it wasn't