# Receive response as NSDictionary instead of NSData

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, nsjsonserialization

I'm trying to get the response from the server as `NSDictionary` instead of `NSData`, so first I'm using AFNetworking library and the server request these settings to be HTTP not `JSON` serializer as the following :

```
self.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer() as AFHTTPResponseSerializer
self.requestSerializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer() as AFHTTPRequestSerializer
self.requestSerializer.HTTPMethodsEncodingParametersInURI = NSSet(array: ["GET"]) as! Set<String>

self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(objects: "application/json","text/json","text/javascript","text/html") as? Set<String>
```

Next is when i get the response from the server it comes to be `NSData` and its because I'm using `AFHTTPRequestSerializer()` and here is my code :

```
self.POST(addUserURL, parameters: dictionary, progress: nil, success: { (task, responseObject) -> Void in


   print(responseObject)


    }) { (task, error) -> Void in


}
```

Also inside AFNetworking block its not allowed to handle try and catch for `NSJSONSerializtion` which can be a possible solution but it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AFNetworking returning NSCFData; issue with registerHTTPOperationClass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558992/afnetworking-returning-nscfdata-issue-with-registerhttpoperationclass)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSJSONSerialization` for that as shown in below code :

```
do {
    let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseObject, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
    // use jsonObject here
} catch {
    print("json error: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: i am getting : `json error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}`

Comment: because its AFHTTPResponseSerializer so i cannot set reading options to allow fragments, i couldn't find solution for it in the whole internet !

Comment: Well, its returning the following : ` json error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}` means its not a JSON format . what can i do then ?

Comment: There is lots of same issues: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Invalid+value+around+character+0.&oq=Invalid+value+around+character+0.&aqs=chrome..69i57.654j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

As response that you get from the server doesn't have top level object that is either `Array` or `Dictionary` you have to specify custom reading options in that should be used by *AFNetworking*.

In order to do that you have to set `responseSerializer` property on an instance of `AFURLSessionManager` class. You can do it as follows:

```
let sessionManager = OLFURLSessionManager.init() //you probably want to keep session manager as a singleton
sessionManager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer.serializerWithReadingOptions(.AllowFragments)
//you should use that instance of session manager to create you data tasks
```

After that you should be able to correctly parse response from the server as follows: